# Unable to load Schema -- angular.json file

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting below error in `angular.json` file , where schema is not  loading properly, getting error unable to load schema, first line of below code giving me error, see below

```
{
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "mrr": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
```

both `angular.json` and `node_modules` is in the same level.

Comment: Try changing the path to "$schema":"./node_modules\\@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json". It works for me.

Comment: Experiencing this issue on macOS. The file is indeed in the directory listed. It even recognizes the `schema.js` file in the same directory (throws a parse error).

Comment: If you are getting this issue on your editor (eg. Visual Studio Code) warnings then just close the editor and open again.

Answer (score 9):

I got this in VSCode when I accidentally started it without first running "npm install" in an Angular project after restructuring my work directory and wiping out some node_modules directories in the process to avoid time-consuming copy operations.

Naturally, when I got the error I didn't even bother to check if node_modules was there, I "just knew" that it was. (I had in fact already run "npm install" in all but that one project directory.)

After closing VSCode, running "npm install" in the Angular project directory and starting VSCode again, the error went away.

Answer (score 4):

Hi Abhishek is a problem related to Angular 9 or Node 12  i had the same issue 
i had the same issue so i rollback to node 11 and angular 8 and everything is fine

[Update]
i update angular and node and everything is fine
the problem is solved in 9.1.6 you can check the issue on github https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35154

Steps i follow

- `npm cache clean`
- `npm install -g @angular/cli`

> If you are having trouble with npm install, use the -verbose option to see more details.

- after all of this `ng update`

This will fix this error.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue with `node 10` and `angular 10`. Also, as of `npm 5` the `npm cache clean` command throws an error explaining that the command is no longer necessary. Alternatives are `npm cache verify` or `npm cache clean --force`.

Answer (score 0):

Open your project in file explorer, then close VS Code. In your project delete the 'node_modules' folder. Next open VS Code again run npm install command in your terminal. All the modules will be installed again and the issued should be gone now.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by deleting my npm catch folder and reinstalling Angular CLI.

Answer (score -4):

Open IDE as administrator or provide full access to user on the root folder